# Match floating point ONLY with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a working regex that matches floating point as well as integer but I need one to only match floating point (number of decimals can be any).

This is what I have so far

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^-?(?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How do I mod it to only match the floating point?

Comment: A small correct: it won't work if you have a plus sign at the start, like `+1234.56`. If you want this to match too, try `^[-+]?(?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$`.

Comment: This regex is ... weird to say it mildly. Why the positive lookahead? why the IgnoreCase flag? Why is the fraction optional if you don't want to match integers?

Comment: Why not simple `^[-+]?\d+\.\d+$`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's why all questions should include a [mcve]. A lot of things are not defined (e.g. is `.5` valid?)

Comment: @Manfred The point of this site to post code in progress..when I have no code, I get people comment and when I do, I also have you comment. I am confused

Comment: @sarsnake I think you missed my point. Include some examples what should and what shouldn't match. Edit: Oh, and they apparently rephrased the `mcve` (that thing that turned my comment into `minimal reproducible example`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is (I've split it into groups for the explanation):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\+?)([0-9]*)(\.)([0-9]+)$");
```

Explanation:

- Group 1 - an optional plus sign at the beginning.
- Group 2 - optional digits before the dot (why optional? because, for example, `.345` is a valid number - and stands for `0.345`).
- Group 3 - the decimal dot.
- Group 4 - numbers after the dot. One comment: This regex will accept numbers such as `12345.0` although is not a really decimal. I don't see how to solve this just with regex (without code).

Comment: My problem... I've splitted it to groups after I wrote it, and the `*` in the third group must be at the end of the second. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! it can't be negative - sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: @sarsnake Fixed :-)

Comment: Chayim, I get an exception with C# if I type in .8989 number (no leading o). System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=parsing "^(+?)([0-9]*)(\.)([0-9]+)$" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: Any way to avoid this exception?

Comment: Fixed. The problem was that you should put `\\` before single plus.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one

```
Regex regex = new> Regex(@"^([-+]?)(([0]{1})|([1-9]+([0-9]*)))(\.)([0-9]+)$");
```

- Group 1: Optional "-" sing on the begin.
- Group 2 - 5: The number begin whit 0 OR begin whit another num (1-9)
  one or more. In this Case is not posible to match (EX: 001.55 - It's
  not a float number).
- Group 6 - Include "."
- Group 7 - Include one or more (0-9)